# Can someone trace me through this using the values (1,1)

Tags: java, function, recursion

I have been given this on a mock programming exam and I am not too good with this type of thing, can someone explain to me how I would go through something like the following? change the values to the one in the question if you feel like it explains it better. It is the final else which is really throwing me off. Thank you for the help.

```
public int function( int a, int b)
{
    if (a<=0){
        return b;
    }
    else if (b<=0)
    {
        return function( a-2, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        return function (function (a-1, b-1), b-1);

    }
```

Comment: Take small values (`a = 2, b = 2`) for example and try to see which calls are made and how the method works. Doing it on paper would be easier to see than looking at your screen.

Comment: Tracing recursive methods can be challenging, so it's important that you keep track of what's going on in memory on paper step by step. Start with small values, and work your way up. Check your work by running the program.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the patience to write out what you're asking for here, but I suggest it would be most useful for you to run it in the Eclipse debugger (or Netbeans, or whatever) step-by-step and see for yourself.

Comment: output is always 0, with 1,1 :)

Comment: Pen(cil) and paper is your friend here - just write down each step. The method is simple it's just the recursion that's throwing you off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I will step through other values so you can learn how to do it yourself.

lets take the values `2,2` for example.

check the first if statement(`if (a<=0)`) to see if its valid

`a=2` so replace `a` with the value `2`

is `2 <= 0`? Nope. Lets go to the next statement

`else if (b<=0)`
NOTE: `else if` is essentially a statement that it used if the previous if statement for fails.

`b = 2` is `2<=0`?  Nope. ONTO THE NEXT ONE!

`else` handles everything that fails under the first `if` and all the proceeding `else ifs`

So just plug in the values.

```
a = 2 b = 2
return function (function (a-1, b-1), b-1);
```

-->

```
return function (function (2-1, 2-1), 2-1); 
-> return function (function (1, 1), 1);
```

You can go two ways with this keep recurring down or logically think about it.

Now... lets start noticing a pattern here and look for a base case (usually used for recursive functions like these) so you notice `return b` on the first if statement will ALWAYS be the actual returning result in the end and all the other recurring will stem off that result, because that's the only real value you will return. Now we got that established 
How can we get to that value? if statement `a<=0` is the only way to get there. You start noticing the relationships.

---

input `a <= b` or `a <= 0` output `b`

input `a > 0` `a > b` output `0`

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your (1,1) as `a = 1` and `b = 1`. That said:

`a = 1 > 0`, the enter condition is false, so the first branch is not taken:

```
if (a<=0)
```

We go on until the second branch. `b = 1 > 0` the enter condition is false again, so we won't take this branch neither:

```
else if (b<=0)
```

eventually, we reach the `else` branch and we take it:

```
else
```

So we land in this line:

```
    return function (function (a-1, b-1), b-1);
```

There is a recursion, here! First call is `function (a-1, b-1)`, so we are calling `function` with `a = 1 - 1 = 0` and `b = 1 - 1 = 0`. Let's start again as above:

`a = 0`, so we take the first branch:

```
if (a <= 0)
```

and we return `b = 0`.

Now, it's time for the second recursion. We have `a = function(a - 1, b - 1) = 0` and `b = 1 - 1 = 0`. It's still `a = 0` and `b = 0`, so the result will be `0` as above.

Finally, we return `0`.

Comment: Please remember that the `a` and `b` from each of the three invocations is a different variable. If it is not clear to you, then I will rename the variables.